# EnvelopedCMS with AES and rsaEncryption (PKCS#1 v1.5 padding instead of v2 (OAEP) padding) possible?

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, aes, rsa

I've been using .NET for cryptographic purposes a bit. Up to now, I used 3DES (Oid 1.2.840.113549.3.7) in combination with rsaEncryption (Oid 1.2.840.113549.1.1.1, RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5). While the first one has now to be replaced by **AES** (Oid 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.42), I still have to use **rsaEncryption** / **RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5**, not **RSAES-OAEP**.

If I just pass an additional argument to the EnvelopedCMS constructor that I'm calling, I can switch from 3DES to AES:

```
    ContentInfo plainContent = new ContentInfo(new Oid("1.2.840.113549.1.7.1"), data);

    EnvelopedCms encryptedMessage = new EnvelopedCms(plainContent); // using 3DES
    // EnvelopedCms encryptedMessage = new EnvelopedCms(plainContent, new AlgorithmIdentifier(new Oid("2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.42")));  // for AES (id-aes256-CBC)

    CmsRecipient recipient = new CmsRecipient(cert);
    encryptedMessage.Encrypt(recipient);

    byte[] encryptedBytes = encryptedMessage.Encode();
```

That's fine so far. Unfortunately, some recipients cannot decrypt my messages, althought they are able to decrypt AES. Looking at the ASN.1 structure tells me that not only 3DES changed to AES, but also rsaEncryption (1.2.840.113549.1.1.1) was replaced by **RSAES-OAEP** (1.2.840.113549.1.1.7). Can I somehow force to still use **RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5** with EnvelopedCMS? Or do you see another problem in switching 3DES->AES?

Edit: In case I cannot change the padding that easily to v1.5, what other options do I have? Manually calling the CryptoServiceProviders and build up the PKCS#7 envelope on my own? Are there more elegant ways?

Comment: I've googled quite a bit, but I could not find much. Note that PKCS#1 v1.5 has some significant vulnerabilities (explained in the RSA v2.1 RFC) that you might want to avoid. It may be secure, but it does require quite a few checks to be secure. OAEP *does* make more sense with regard to security of the protocol.

Comment: I'd prefer OAEP as far as I understand. Unfortunately, I just have to follow to given protocol. Because my messages cannot be decrypted since chance 3des->aes, the only difference in my system compared to the given rules is the usage of OAEP instead of rsaEncryption. Any other idea for implementation (using preferrably only .NET classes)?

Comment: As far as I understand it so far, BouncyCastle is quite powerful (even though not well documented for C#). Any ideas how to achieve a solution there?

Comment: I would not have too much problems implementing a solution for Bouncy Castle as it would come floating back to me. It certainly is configurable and at least it is easy to get the source if it isn't. Unfortunately I don't know a solution out of the top of my head though. I'd certainly would consider it a good candidate to solve this particular problem. In the unlikely event that it doesn't support the solution you can simply fix and recompile it.

Comment: Thank you for you considerations. Since a deadline was putting a lot of pressure on this, I now took a commercial library (http://www.cryptosys.net) providing a solution for that particular problem out of the box. Hopefully, that should now be solved for the moment. Sorry for not finally providing a smooth solution using only .NET.

Comment: Glad you got it solved for now. You can just leave the question open, it would be interesting to see if it gets a response in time.

Answer (score 4):

The .NET Framework EnvelopedCms is built on top of Windows CAPI CryptMsg* functions. CryptMsgOpenToEncode supports two ways of encoding recipients, one of which is conditionally compiled (though I haven't been able to identify when it is not available; I suspect it's a Win9x vs NT4/WinXP compat problem).

On a whim I looked to see what could flip it to use the other codepath, and if that would change your result here. It turns out, yes, making it internally "useCms" results in the recipient encryption algorithm being 1.2.840.113549.1.1.1.

#### Option 1) Use SubjectKeyIdentifier identification

If you're interoperating with another system, as is the case here, make sure that the certificate has an explicit SubjectKeyIdentifier extension before using this identification form. .NET/Windows will make up an implicit value if there isn't an explicit one, and not all CMS implementations will match the recipient certificate in that case (e.g. OpenSSL).

You accomplish this by changing your CmsRecipient to

```
CmsRecipient recipient = new CmsRecipient(SubjectIdentifierType.SubjectKeyIdentifier, cert);
```

#### Option 2) Add an UnprotectedAttribute

EnvelopedCms allows for other metadata to be added onto the message unencrypted. Specifying any of these values makes the encryptor/encoder use the alternate codepath.

Before calling Encrypt add

```
// Pkcs9DocumentName requires a non-empty string.
// You can use any AsnEncodedData value, though.
encryptedMessage.UnprotectedAttributes.Add(new Pkcs9DocumentName("a"));
```

Each of those worked in local testing.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for this answer! Do you understand why adding UnprotectedAttribute -or- using SubjectIdentifierType.SubjectKeyIdentifier changes KEA to RSA (1.2.840.113549.1.1.1)?

Comment: @PawelLesnikowski Those two features came in a later version of the CMS spec, and thus need a newer API call into Windows. The older form takes just a certificate and picks OAEP (since it has better security under certain attack models). The newer form takes the encryption algorithm as an input, which .NET fills in using the certificate's public key algorithm identifier (RSA) without uplifting RSA to RSA_OAEP.

Comment: useCms==false is the newer version?

Comment: @PawelLesnikowski No, `useCms==true` means that it uses the `rgCmsRecipients` field of CMSG_ENVELOPED_ENCODE_INFO (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377828(v=vs.85).aspx), instead of `rgpRecipents`. But that significantly changes the interaction between .NET and Windows.

Comment: I understand the mechanics (I think), but I don't understand the reason. Why there are 2 ways of encrypting envelope cms? Do I understand correctly that UnprotectedAttributes are 'new' API? If so why using it forces AES to be used with older key exchange (RSA instead of RSAES-OAEP)

Comment: @PawelLesnikowski Yes, UnprotectedAttributes and SubjectKeyIdentrifier are from CMS version 2. The older form was limited to either version 0 or 1. The older form of the API probably worked on more versions of Windows that .NET needed to support at the time. The newer form is more complex and required a change in .NET to move from PKCS#1 padding to OAEP for the KEK when AES was the CEK... no one told .NET, so the change didn't happen. Anything further is essentially asking "why do bugs happen?" or "did you know software sometimes doesn't get updated after new RFCs come out?".